# User Agent Style-sheet Issue

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have an issue on my [website](http://demo.rtdsllc.com). If you go to the consulting page you'll notice that the li are aligned left. Firebug yields the follow in regards to the styles being applied:

```
text-align: -webkit-match-parent;
```

How do i get rid of that so that it has a natural indent like regular li's?

Comment: The same thing is happening on the downloads page.

Comment: This is part of the of the [default display properties in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html#li-display). What's wrong with that? If you'll use "older" DOCTYPE I believe you won't get that default value.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thank you very much. Can you recommend a DOCTYPE? Also can you write it as an answer so that I can mark it as such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is part of the of the [default display properties in HTML5](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/li.html#li-display).

If you wish to "give up" on HTML5 you can use the previous version:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
```

This is HTML 4.01 strict - I believe you won't get that default value using it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you reference a few css pages so open up the one that has the element with the

```
text-align: -webkit-match-parent
```

and comment out that piece to start.  then review the site and see if that returns things to a normal LI indent.

Comment: That's a user agent stylesheet not one that i call.